# iOS Delegate returning nil (Swift 1.2)

Tags: ios, swift, delegates

I'm trying to write a little RSS parser for my app, I have a XML parser class that i'm trying to implement a delegate into so my RSS class can be told when parsing is complete. But i'm having some issues.

So i have my delegate:

```
protocol MyXmlDelegate
{
    func onComplete ()
}
```

then in my XML parser class I have reference to it:

```
var someDelegate: MyXmlDelegate?
```

I call the delegate function when needed:

```
public func parserDidEndDocument(parser: NSXMLParser) {
    println("parsing finished")

    if someDelegate == nil {
        println ("Delegate nil bro")
    }
    else
    {
        someDelegate!.onComplete()
    }
}
```

then my RSS class implements the delegate:

```
class RSSFeed : NSObject, MyXmlDelegate
```

the class sets the parser' delegate to self:

```
init (feedURL url: String)
{
    super.init()

    parser = XMLParser(contentsOfURL: NSURL (string: url)!)!
    parser!.someDelegate = self
}
```

the rss class implements the delegate function:

```
func onComplete() {
    println ("on complete...")
}
```

Now when I run the app, the parser completes and prints:
"parsing finished",
"Delegate nil bro"

So why is my delegate nil? 
Have I missed something obvious?

Comment: Try debugging the didSet method for delegate. That way, you'll know what happens with it. I'm assuming: A) RSSFeed gets deallocated in the meantime (is it retained? Is delegate weak or strong?); B) It finishes parsing before delegate is set; C) Something else sets delegate to nil;

Comment: thanks for your help milo! yeah you're correct (B), parsing was finished before the delegate was set.

Comment: As an aside, explicit comparison with nil is not the recommended way if unwrapping optionals. Instead of 'if someDelegate == nil ...' try a construct that starts 'if let delegate = someDelegate ...'. Search for optional unwrapping for more details.

Comment: @AliBeadle thanks, is there any benefit to doing it that way? is it better for performance? or is it just a best practise type deal? I come from a C# background.

Comment: I doubt it affects performance much. It is neater I guess (particularly in more complex situations of nested unwraps and multiple references to the unwrapped optionals) and perhaps less prone to error - those !s can cause crashes if you misplace them and an 'if let' avoids the need for a !